# Favorite a question

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

Is there a way to know who favorited ★ a question?

If yes, how?

If not, why does it have to be 'private information'?

Comment: If you can narrow down the pool of users to a couple of "suspects", you can check their profile pages with the list of favourites. For example you can see my "favourites" here https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter?tab=favorites (the quotation marks because I use it as some kind of bookmark to be able to find some questions again)

Comment: @samcarter Well that would be the hard way. What if there are "100 suspects" or what if you have absolutely no idea who could be.

Comment: That's why my comment started with "if" :)

Comment: @samcarter Ah. ok :)

Comment: off-topic: please don't interpret too much in any counts of favourites. Users use this button for all kinds of purposes (to compensate other missing functionalities in the UI of this site), knowing who favourites a question would not be really useful, unless you ask the user why he/she/it favoured the post

Comment: @samcarter Yes, you are totally right, I was just being curious.

Comment: @samcarter is right when she said users use the "favorite" button for any kind of purpose: in my case, other than my favorite posts, I use it also to flag the question I think I could ask, to answer when I have time, if nobody else already did it meanwhile. However, the question is very interesting, +1!

Comment: @CarLaTeX it is, isn't? :D

Comment: Absolutely! :):):)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.
I wrote a simple query, which you can find on Data StackExchange [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/954306/who-favourited-this-question?).

It takes in an input of `Question ID`, and returns a list of `User ID` and `User names` who favourited that particular question.

E.g. Question ID **8021** is [Is there a (La)TeX distribution running on iPad?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8021/117534)

Running the query on this gives 11 favourites:

[image]

[image]

It's easy to verify that these people actually did favourite that question by going to their profiles and checking their activity.

With regards to the privacy concerns, there has been a discussion on Meta before, [Can there be an option to keep your list of favourites private?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140778).

---

#### Addendum

For those who do not know how to get the question ID, it'll be on the URL. For example:

> `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad`

And I decided to post the query here for posterity:

```
-- Find who favourited a particular question

DECLARE @QuestionID int = ##QuestionID##

SELECT
  v.CreationDate AS [Voted On],
  v.UserId AS [User ID],
  u.DisplayName AS [User Name]
FROM
  Votes v
  INNER JOIN
  Users u ON v.UserId = u.Id
WHERE v.VoteTypeId = 5 AND v.PostID = ##QuestionID##
ORDER BY v.CreationDate DESC;
```

Comment: Great! I run it on some of my questions and I surprisingly found out that users who flagged them, in general, aren't "habitué" of the site!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your request does not work in all cases. There are users who are not displayed. For example, this question has two favorites, your query only displays one. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468363/138900

Comment: @AndréC Perhaps the database is not updated yet.

Comment: Perhaps. This question has 2 favorites, only one is displayed : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468363/138900

Comment: Does this still works? I am trying to use it but does not return anything.